# Blowing a fuse when turning on trailer lights

Tags: jeep, wrangler

Just purchased a 5 x 8 utility trailer.  Lights on the back of the trailor were not wired in, wires were hanging loose both sides.  Wired lights according to instructions, pass. Side green brown, drivers side yellow brown. With that all done connected trailer harness to vehicle plug to test lights everything worked as expected, brake lights, blinkers but when I turned the parking.lights on a fuse blew.  Would u have any idea what may cause this?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'd suggest your parking lights have a direct to ground. You can check this with a DMM on Ohms to see continuity between the wire and the frame of the trailer. You'd also want to check it against the ground wire in the wiring (if it has one ... could ground through the tongue/hitch interface).

Comment: A faulty bulb can also cause this - remove all the parking bulbs and test - if it still blows then check the wires - note the earth or return is usually done by a wire in the trailer wiring socket - used to be the white wire for the UK...